# Using push notification for an iOS App not in the app store

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am working on an iOS app targeted primarily for iPhones and iPads which I believe will not be approved by Apple to be in the app store.

I have read about sideloading in which a user downloads the IPA directly and chooses to trust my Apple ID, my question is whether I will be able to use push notifications in such a scenario since my app heavily relies on them.

Thanks,

Comment: yes, with enterprise account you can build in-house version of your app and use push notification

Comment: I don't believe I qualify for an in-house version of the app, it should be targeted to the public and it is not a corporate app, I just don't believe the app will be approved by Apple.

Comment: I have an app that signed with an enterprise account, and it has more than 50000 users, there is no problem with push notification.

Comment: @Hamed unfortunatly I don't qualify for an enterprise account according to Apple:

-Have 100 or more employees.
-Be a legal entity. We do not accept DBAs, fictitious businesses, trade names, or branches.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enterprise account and you don't want distribute your app for random users.
You can use universal in house – mobile provision with notifications. It will be work.

Comment: I see multiple suggestions of that, but in order to qualify for an enterprise account you need to have 100 or more employees and be a legal entity, and I am just a private person.

Question is if I can use a plain developer APNs certificate with users who choose to sideload my app for instance or something like that is not even possible.

Comment: For enterprise account you need legal entity but don't need have 100 or more employees. If you have only developer account – you can add 100 device in your developer account if you want more you need enterprise account.